# Word meaning relating to or involving humans or people

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I need a word to fill the blank in this sentence: "The hurricane was one of the most *blank*-deadly events in history."

The human death count was recorded, but not the death count not for other species, so it was definitely a deadly event for humans, but the toll taken on other species was not known.

At the moment I'm using *human* for this purpose, but *human-deadly* doesn't sound quite right, nor as good as possible.

I understand that without the word, the statement would generally be taken as  referring to humans but I would prefer to specify.

Comment: Pragmatics is,  as usual, involved. Even with no further textual context, _The hurricane was one of the most deadly events in history_ would be taken as referring to human deaths. If you need to be specific here, _human death count_ is quite acceptable - it sounds odd because you'd almost always just say _death count_. Lengthier constructions ('the number of animals killed ...'; 'the death toll amongst primates ...') would be used where required for other populations.

Comment: The hurricane was one of the deadliest events in history- and not just for humans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Deadly* is generally taken to refer to humans, and so does not need a qualifier. In fact, I can't actually think of a word that would be comfortably and effectively used in the way you want to use it.

Also, we usually say "deadliest" instead of "most deadly."

It is understood that we are talking about people in such cases, unless we specify something else. Therefore, if you want to indicate it killed a lot of alligators, you would say something like, "For the alligator population, it was one of the deadliest events...."

If you still feel the need to emphasize that you're talking about human beings, I would suggest you say "in human history" rather than simply "in history."

*Addendum* to address the new final sentence of your edited question:

I really can't come up with a word that works for your purpose. If you want to specify that you are just talking about how many people died, I suggest you restructure the sentence. Here are a few possibilities:

> The hurricane killed more people than most other events in recorded history.
>
> The hurricane was one of the deadliest human tragedies in history.
>
> The hurricane was an event more deadly to humans than almost any other natural disaster in the history of the planet.

And there are many more.

Comment: Humans record history of other species' too, so it still doesn't sound right.

Comment: It sounds right to John. It sounds right to me. Wikipedia doesn't feel the need to qualify either 'loss of life' or 'death toll' ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_disasters_by_death_toll ).

Comment: Umm, well, no, not exactly. History is human. When did you ever read a "history" of any other race? And if this doesn't sound right to you, I have to tell you, get used to the way it sounds, because it is the standard usage. Notice that Edwin's comment agrees with my answer in almost every detail. And Jim's comment subsequent to Edwin's also reflects exactly the same thing. (He writes, "one of the deadliest events in history," which you can see is taken as necessarily _human_, because then he shows how it is necessary to add a clause about non-humans if you want to talk about them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you're looking for is "**anthropinistically**". ("A descriptive term for the consideration of things from a purely human viewpoint or only in *their relationships to mankind and **the needs of humans*** and their destinies.")

Not a common word, but I do see a use for it (though it's true that "deadly" seems to imply this by itself). In studying personality types, I was looking for words that characterized a more "personal" vs "impersonal" perspective, but since "personal" can mean different things, I looked for other terms, and now "mechanistic" seemed to fit the impersonal perspective, and the best analogue I could find so far, would be anthropinistic (though it is a bit long and clunky).

Comment: Where is the definition between the quotation marks from? Also, searching Google for "anthropinistically" only finds this post.